# How to create a loop for the following case?

Tags: c#, loops

```
/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]
/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[4]

/html/body/table/tr[3]/td[2]
/html/body/table/tr[3]/td[4]

/html/body/table/tr[5]/td[2]
/html/body/table/tr[5]/td[4]
```

So, the index of tr[ ] would be odd numbers, and td[ ] would always be either 2 or 4.

Comment: are you looking at creating the text aswell? Ie /html/body/table/

Comment: @Jethro: yes. I need to do have a loop for something like Selenium.GetText("xpath=/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(int i = 1; i < bound; i += 2) {
    for(int j = 2; j <= 4; j += 2) {
        Console.WriteLine(
            String.Format("/html/body/table/tr[{0}]/td[{1}]", i, j)
        );
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: I'd probably make a small comment about bound (in this case it would need to be at least 6 for his example.

Comment: Why use two loops? A single loop with two writelines would be more readable given both tr's are indexed of the same value, and the td is always 2 & 4.

Comment: @Calgary Coder: So I don't repeat myself! (If you refactor, to change the format or whatever, you have to change it in two places).

Answer (score 3):

You could do something as simple as

```
for(tr = 1; tr < maxodd+1; tr += 2;)
{
    //pseudoimplementation
    /html/bod/table/tr[tr]/td[2]
    /html/bod/table/tr[tr]/td[4]

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The most naive case:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 6; i += 2) {
    Console.WriteLine("html/body/table/tr[" + i + "]/td[2]");
    Console.WriteLine("html/body/table/tr[" + i + "]/td[4]");
}
```